# Pass Data between route in Slim

Tags: php, slim-3

I am new to slim and I want to pass Data between two routes (apps)

```
$app->get('/answer', function (Request $request, Response $response) use($talk,$voiceName,$message){

    // submit this data
    $request = $request->withAttribute('username','XXXXXX');

    return $response->withJson($ncco);
});


$app->post('/webhooks/comfrimcardinput', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) use($talk,$voiceName,$message){

    //  Get this data
    $foo = $request->getAttribute('username');

    return $response->withJson($ncco);
});
```

Comment: What version of slim?

Comment: Slim 3 is the version

Comment: please explain what the code you've shown does and what it does not. What's the expected and the actual behavior? What's your question?

Comment: I have a web hook that fist step goes to answer route gets some data and after that is will goto /webhooks/comfrimcardinput route.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to pass information/data between two routes that get called individually.

Since the request and response objects are generated for each route and only available in the context of that route, it is not possible to attach data to that objects that will persist through page-loads/sessions.

You need to use some kind of storage for persistent data. There are several options for you available. Some store the information server-side, others store them in the browser/client-side. Which one the best solution for your use-case is depends on the kind of data you want to store.

Server-side:

- Files
- Database

Client-side:

- sessionStorage (only available from javascript)
- localStorage (only available from javascript)
- Cookies (available from php & javascript)

**Cookies in PHP:**

```php
// write a cookie
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* valid for 1 hour (3600 secods) */

// read a cookie
$value = $_COOKIE["TestCookie"];
```

More Information on cookies in PHP: [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), [$_COOKIE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

Comment: Thanks but  a web hook access the php file. and Cookie And session dos not work

Comment: If a webhook is accessing your application and that webhook cant handle cookies, then you can still store the data server-side.